# python function doesn't return result

Tags: python-3.x

Hello everyone I am trying to solve the following problem from leetcode and I am facing the following problem: my function is not returning a value

```
def makeGood(s: str) -> str:
    print('fisrst s: ', s)
    s_list = list(s)
    for n in range(len(s)-1):
        print('n: ', n)
        if s[n].lower() == s[n+1].lower() and s[n] != s[n+1]:
            s_list.remove(s[n])
            s_list.remove(s[n + 1])
            print('list: ', len(s_list))
            s = ''.join(s_list)
            if len(s_list) == 0:
                print('00000')
                print(s)
                break
            else:
                makeGood(s)
    print('out')
    return s


res = makeGood("abBAcC")
print('res: ', res)
```

After executing I have the following output:

```
    fisrst s:  abBAcC
n:  0
n:  1
list:  4
fisrst s:  aAcC
n:  0
list:  2
fisrst s:  cC
n:  0
list:  0
00000

out
n:  1
```

So my question is why is the function not returning a value and trying to continue processing?

Answer (score -1):

Hi I took a look at this and I believe your issue is with your out.

Even when you finish processing the output is still 1 so your for loop will never finish.

Here's my debug output when I was playing with this:

```
Input:  abBAcC
DEBUG-1: s_list contains - ['a', 'b', 'B', 'A', 'c', 'C']
DEBUG-2: index of n =  0
DEBUG-12: Exiting the IF
DEBUG-2: index of n =  1
DEBUG-3: n is now b
DEBUG-4: s[n] is b
DEBUG-5: s_list contains - ['a', 'B', 'A', 'c', 'C']
DEBUG-6: s_list contains - ['a', 'A', 'c', 'C']
DEBUG-7: list length is now : 4
DEBUG-8: s = aAcC
Input:  aAcC
DEBUG-1: s_list contains - ['a', 'A', 'c', 'C']
DEBUG-2: index of n =  0
DEBUG-3: n is now a
DEBUG-4: s[n] is a
DEBUG-5: s_list contains - ['A', 'c', 'C']
DEBUG-6: s_list contains - ['c', 'C']
DEBUG-7: list length is now : 2
DEBUG-8: s = cC
Input:  cC
DEBUG-1: s_list contains - ['c', 'C']
DEBUG-2: index of n =  0
DEBUG-3: n is now c
DEBUG-4: s[n] is c
DEBUG-5: s_list contains - ['C']
DEBUG-6: s_list contains - []
DEBUG-7: list length is now : 0
DEBUG-8: s = 
DEBUG-9: If s = nothing print 00000
00000

DEBUG-10: Value of s is 
DEBUG-13: Exiting the FOR
DEBUG-11: in the ELSE
DEBUG-12: Exiting the IF
DEBUG-2: index of n =  1
```

And here's the code

```
def makeGood(s: str) -> str:
    print('Input: ', s)
    s_list = list(s)
    print(f'DEBUG-1: s_list contains - {s_list}')
    for n in range(len(s)+1):
        print(f'DEBUG-2: index of n =  {n}')
        if s[n].lower() == ((s[n+1]).lower()) and (s[n] != s[n+1]):
            print(f'DEBUG-3: n is now {s[n].lower()}')
            print(f'DEBUG-4: s[n] is {s[n]}')
            s_list.remove(s[n])
            print(f'DEBUG-5: s_list contains - {s_list}')
            s_list.remove(s[n + 1])
            print(f'DEBUG-6: s_list contains - {s_list}')
            print(f'DEBUG-7: list length is now : {len(s_list)}')
            s = ''.join(s_list)
            print(f'DEBUG-8: s = {s}')
            if len(s_list) == 0:
                print(f'DEBUG-9: If s = nothing print 00000')
                print('00000')

                print(s)
                print(f'DEBUG-10: Value of s is {s}')
                break
            else:
                makeGood(s)
        
                print('DEBUG-11: in the ELSE')
        print('DEBUG-12: Exiting the IF')
        
    print('DEBUG-13: Exiting the FOR')
    return s


res = makeGood("abBAcC")
print('res: ', res)
```

When doing this in Jupyter notebooks it clearly states it is an "IndexError: string index out of range"

The interesting bit of the traceback is:

```
Input In [29], in makeGood(s)
      5 for n in range(len(s)+1):
      6     print(f'DEBUG-2: index of n =  {n}')
----> 7     if s[n].lower() == ((s[n+1]).lower()) and (s[n] != s[n+1]):
      8         print(f'DEBUG-3: n is now {s[n].lower()}')
      9         print(f'DEBUG-4: s[n] is {s[n]}')
```

Take a look at that and I am sure you will work it out